# Why does Ctrl+ESC Open startmenu?

Tags: windows

I have no idea what happen to my win-key but when I press it, it does not open the start menu, if I press ctrl + esc, it brings up the start menu. how did this happen?. I want the Win-key to open start menu, not ctrl+esc.

Answer (score 3):

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> has alway opened the start menu](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126449). Most likely I would say you've held down the <kbd>Win</kbd> too long and inadvertently enabled [Filter keys](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20disable%20filter%20keys&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or [Sticky Keys](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20disable%20sticky%20keys). Also possible, your <kbd>Win</kbd> is physically damaged. Try pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and see if it brings up the Run dialog.